# How to override a default value with other value django models

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a problem with django. In my model, I have a JSON-Field which stores as default an empty list. When trying to append a value to that list, this doesn´t work. No matter whether it´s another object or a string. Going to the field, its still empty then. I would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

models.py

```
followers = models.JSONField(default={
    "followers": []
})
```

(the "followers" field is in the Client class)

views.py

```
current_user = Client.objects.get(id=response.user.id)
current_user.followers["followers"].append("Some Name")
```

Comment: Have you called `current_user.save()` method?

Comment: You should not work with a dictionary *object* as default, since then all the new constructed items will refer to the *same* dictionary.

Comment: Oh man, that was the error. Sorry haha it was so easy xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems here. First you need to *save* the object to the database. Furthermor3e using `{"followers": []}` as default is *not* a good idea. As the [documentation on the JSONField says](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#jsonfield):

> If you give the field a default, ensure it’s a **callable such as `dict`** (for an empty default) **or a callable** that returns a dict (such as a function). **Incorrectly using `default={}` creates a mutable default that is shared** between all instances of JSONField.

You thus should define a function that will *create* a (new) dictionary, like:

```
def default_followers():
    return {'followers': []}

class MyModel(models.Model):
    # …
    followers = models.JSONField(default=default_followers)
```

If you want to implement a follower-followee model, you should not use a JSONField, but work with a `ManyToManyField`, since relational databases are optimized to work with such tables, and it will guarantee referential integrity.

Comment: First of all, thank you very much. Really, this helps me a lot. I tried using a ```ManyToManyField``` , but I have to link it to other classes then. And the "followers" field is in my "Client" class. Does that mean I have to create a seperate class for other users so that the ```ManyToManyField``` can be linked to them?

Comment: You can make a `ManyToManyField` that refers to another model, so if you have a `Client` that has a `ManyToManyField` to `Poster`, then you thus create a junction table: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table